# Application for viewing installed Documentation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation, documentation, helpfile

I don't remember the name of application or package which I  used in Ubuntu 11.04 to view the default installed Documentation or manually installed documentations from synaptic.

It was pretty helpful. I tried searching but end up nowhere.

I tried YELP *(Which is Ubuntu's help system)* but it doesn't provide functionalities for viewing  manually installed documentations.

For Example : I installed `python2.7-doc` package from "synaptic" package manager and doesn't shows up in Yelp.

I want the functionality to view the documentation installed by documentation packages. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  tool which view `manpages` in browser, it is called `doccentral`. You can install it with the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get install doc-central
```

Then open a terminal and type `doccentral  package-name`, for example

```
    doccentral python
```

Which brings you to your default browser with Contents such as this.

[image]