# How to download the Official man pages from the manpages.Ubuntu.com for Offline viewing

Tags: downloads, manpage

I am talking about this [Precise Man Pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/).

From here i want the entire available [English Language](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/) Man pages **as it is** , so i can view them **offline** in the same format .Simply Browser way, which also makes it portable for **reditribution**.

I am aware that it can be accessed through command line , but the Official site provides attractive description (makes a beginner like me less afraid in reading, learning and understanding them).

By what means and in what way should it be done to achieve the desired Man Pages in same Format.

Using Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit edition.

P.S.: Also is there any way of knowing its size before downloading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here [WebHTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), installed through Synaptic manager.

By which i was able to get the Man Pages as it is from the website .

[image]

though it went for more than 200 MB's , but got the job done.

Answer (score 5):

The man pages are usually get installed with software. So, If you install a software with manpages, the manpages will be automatically installed.

### Manual pages in a Web browser

- #### By installing man2html

  You can install `man2html` package to your computer to view the manual pages in your favorite browser:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install man2html
  ```
- #### By installing doc-central

  There is another tool which view `manpages` in browser, it is called `doccentral`. You can install it with the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install doc-central
  ```

---

### Downloading manual pages:

You can download the latest manual pages from [here](http://tldp.org/manpages/man.html). The size was also included in the page

---

### Manual pages in *PDF* !:

Yes, you can even get the manual pages in pdf file format. for example, if you want to generate manual page for `man` the command will be :

```
man -t man | ps2pdf - man.pdf.
```

This will generate a manual page, named `man.pdf` in the current directory of the terminal. replace `man` with your desired one, such as `grep` or `apt-get` etc.

---

### Info pages in browser.

*Though it is not asked in the question, I include it as general reference.*

You can also have the GNU info pages *(which are more elaborate and helpful)* in a web browser by installing `info2www` package. The command is below:

```
sudo apt-get install info2www
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I was also considering the portability as major option and concern.

Comment: @tijybba, I have edited the answer according to portability issue

Comment: Honestly i never meant to view the `Installed` man pages in Html format ( sorry if i was unclear about that in question), since i use **XMAN** (though not html) for that which is more convenient for me. But really thanks for other options .

Comment: The doc-Central part in this answer solves one of my Unanswered question, i tried this and it works, if you want to post the **doccentral** part in detail as answer  [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142568/application-or-package-name-for-viewing-all-default-or-manually-installed-doc), i will accept it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wget` to download the entire website. (if the server allows this) like

```
$wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains website.org \
     --no-parent \
```

Here is more details [[`wget` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wget)]

Source: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget