# Downloading Entirety of Lubuntu/Ubuntu Man-pages?

Tags: lubuntu, pdf, 15.10, documentation, manpage

I know about [this page](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads) which is almost exactly what I want. Unfortunately, it is not current.

What I would like to do is to have the entirety of the [Ubuntu man-pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/) in a nice, easy to read, PDF format. I'll accept other formats but I'd prefer an indexed PDF file for simplicity and portability.

I am also aware of [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) which can pull down the pages in HTML format. There are a few reasons that I wish to avoid this - the primary reason being that it's not really a nice thing to do to their bandwidth and servers.

I've searched the Ubuntu site, used an external search engine, and have searched this site. I did find [one answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157531/453950) that led me back to HTTrack which is a potential solution but not the ideal solution and, as mentioned, isn't very nice to their servers or bandwidth.

Even more special would be being able to get this specifically for [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation) because there are a few differences in software and I'm an avid Lubuntu user but, if need be, I can make due with just the Ubuntu man-pages.

The reason that I want this is because, well, I'd like to read it - in its entirety. More like a book than like a file that is called when needed. I want to be able to read it while I only have access to my phone, tablet, or other compute device and in an easier to read format than the man-pages typically use.

---

**EDIT:**

Specifically for Ubuntu (or Lubuntu) version 15.10, as noted in the tags and title. Also, yes - all the man-pages (even redundant and short ones). I'm aware that this is a lot of information which is one of the reasons that I'm trying to avoid using HTTrack.

Comment: You could use wget + the prerequisites option to download the page..... but you need should have all the manual pages you for the packages you have installed via the `man` command - you should be able to pipe the output of the man command to various file formats, which you can then read on various devices

Comment: @Wilf Yeah, thanks. I want the man-pages for *everything* that's available for Ubuntu in the official repositories, installed or not. Therein lies the rub. I know, it's strange. It's still my objective and I've not yet found quite what I'm looking for online and readily available. I'm probably going to have to make it, from the looks of things. I'll be sure to upload it and share it, when I'm done - that way it needn't be done multiple times and I can then keep it up-to-date in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> Even more special would be being able to get this specifically for Lubuntu because there are a few differences in software and I'm an avid Lubuntu user but, if need be, I can make due with just the Ubuntu man-pages.

There are no differences in manpages between Lubuntu and Ubuntu. One of the points of becoming a recognized flavour is using the same repositories as Ubuntu, so the software is identical, it's only the starting points that differ.

Also, http://manpages.ubuntu.com suffers from a bug where identically named manpages from different packages aren't distinguished - the manpages of the last package read show up.

Instead of hammering the manpages site, hammer the repositories.

Get a list of manpages, for, say, the `binary-amd64` architecture (should be identical to the others):

```bsh
mkdir temp
cd temp
curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/Contents-amd64.gz | 
  gunzip | 
  grep 'share/man' |
  sed 's/.* //;s/,/\n/g' | 
  awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | 
  sort -u > packages.txt
while IFS= read -r package
do
    apt-get download "$package"
    dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile "$package"*.deb | tar x ./usr/share/man
    mkdir "$package"-manpages
    find ./usr/share/man/man* -type f -exec mv -t "$package"-manpages {} +
    rm "$package"*.deb
    for page in "$package"-manpages/*
    do
        man -t "$page" | ps2pdf - > "$page".pdf
    done
done < packages.txt
```

If course, this is going to consume an insane amount of bandwidth - the repository servers are used to it, the question is: is *your* network upto the task?

Comment: My network can handle it. I've got a separate line and compute cycles that I can throw at it. :D I've got @kos in chat working on another one so it looks like this is going to get done. I'll upload and share the results, regardless of which way I go, so as to make sure it need only be done once. Also, won't there be differences in the man-pages as Lubuntu has different *default* software than Ubuntu or is all software listed in the man-page site? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For this approach, you will need `html2ps`,`ps2pdf` and a working LaTeX installation. You should be able to install all requirements with

```
sudo apt-get install html2ps ghostscript texlive-latex-base
```

Once you've installed the required packages, run this to get the man pages as pdf files:

```
curl http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/ | 
    grep -oP 'href="\K.*?\.1\.html' | 
        while read man; do 
            wget http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/"$man" && 
                html2ps "$man"  | ps2pdf - "${man/.html/.pdf}"
        done
```

You should now have a (huge) collection of pdf files in the directory you ran the command in. By the way, **make sure to run the command in a new, empty directory**.

Now, to combine them into a single, indexed PDF file, you'll need LaTeX and you'll need to rename them because LaTeX doesn't like `.` in file names:

```
rename 's/\./-/g;s/-pdf/\.pdf/' *pdf
cat <<EoF > man1.tex   
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
EoF
for f in *.pdf; do
    file="${f/.pdf/}"
    printf '\section{%s}\n\includepdf[pages=-]{%s}\n\n' "$file" "$f" >> man1.tex
done
echo "\end{document}" >> man1.tex
pdflatex man1.tex && pdflatex man1.tex
```

The result is an indexed PDF file of all man pages (I only used 10 for testing):

[image]

Comment: This one keeps stopping at `Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at /usr/bin/html2ps line 3409.` It has stopped there twice now. Any ideas?

Comment: @KGIII sounds lika a bug in `html2ps`. I didn't encounter it in the 1st 10 I used for testing. You could try `html2pdf` instead but I didn't find it in the Ubuntu repos. You might have to compile it.

Comment: Hmm... It's not letting me type @ username for some reason, anyhow - I'll compile that and test again later. :D Thanks. I was checking out your code and looking to see if there was a way to support resume. :/ I don't know of a way to do so.

Comment: @KGIII you can't ping me because the owner of a post always gets notified and there's nobody else to ping. As for resuming, just run the first code without the while loop, only the curl, grep and wget. You will then have all the html files locally and can play with them at your leisure.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I've got the locally now. Now to convert 'em. This could be a minute.

Answer (score 0):

> Updated based on Chat discussion

You want to get ***all*** the manpages in PDF (or HTML) form.  No system that I am aware of, nor any Distro for that matter, provides a complete set of all the manpages for your viewing.  That'd be *millions* of pages, and my guess would be lots and lots of storage space being needed, of which would be useless to actually store.  This would also be hammering the manpages server where the manpages exist already in web-viewable format.  If you *really* want to achieve this you'd convert the manpages yourself and download all the packages in the repositories that contain manpages.  (That's also equally evil)

You ***should not have to read all the manpages***, nor do I know why you'd want that many pages.  (Imagine a seven-hundred-thousand volume encyclopedia, that's effectively what you're asking for)

---

> This section was before chat cleared up misconceptions about what was being asked

I don't think there's a 'PDF' for every thing, but you can make PDFs for manpages you wish to use.

[There is a site which contains manpages for different Ubuntu releases for different packages in the Ubuntu repositories.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com)  Assuming the manpage in question in from a Repository package, you can open the manpage there, and then print these to a file (via either Print the Page or otherwise) and then save them as a PDF, which you can then use elsewhere.

The downside: it's one manpage at a time - you'll have to spend time to get the ones you want.

> <sub>(Note: to PDF *all* the manpages would be a hellish project so I doubt you're going to find PDFs for every manpage you want... that'd usually be done by upstream, not Ubuntu).</sub>

Comment: They don't *have* to be in PDF format. Once I get the data (without hammering on their servers - ideally) I can go about manipulating it. I'd prefer to avoid that much effort but I'll go through it, if needed. My main criteria is avoiding hammering on their servers.

Comment: @KGIII Unavoidable, unless you want to download and install all packages that have manpages.  (Basically, Impossible Situation(TM).)

Comment: Following the chat, we're at a bit over 30,000 pages. Hrm... Maybe someone's already done this? It looks like I can slow the requests down with HTTrack and not hammer on the server *too* bad. I may just have to live with an older version from the site linked in my question - I really don't want to beat on their servers without a better reason than "bathroom reading."