# How to download the manpages of all ubuntu packages at one shot?

Tags: manpage

Is there a way to download the manpages of all ubuntu packages without installing the packages. I just want to look up the manpages in a non-ubuntu machine. So I don't want to and can not install the packages.

Comment: Is [the website](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/) insufficient? 

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155743/how-to-download-the-official-man-pages-from-the-manpages-ubuntu-com-for-offline).

Comment: LOL I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699626/downloading-entirety-of-lubuntu-ubuntu-man-pages) a number of years ago. The answers should still be valid.

Comment: @KGIII The solution there is not acceptable. I only want to download the manpages instead of download everything then removing all the files except the manpages.

Comment: @marshki The solution there is not relevant either. I want all manpages on Ubuntu instead of the core manpages.

Comment: @Matigo I want to only download the manpages. Is there website that you provided have a tar file with all the manpages?

Comment: see this for inspiration `https://manpages.ubuntu.com/dman`